# I'm trying to do a search by title and by content, but it gives an error syntax error at or near \"OR\

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to do a search by title and by content, but it gives an error

**Typeorm**

```
select
p.*,
from post p
left join vote v on p.id = v.post_id and v.user_id = $1
where p.is_published = true AND p.title ilike OR p.context::text ilike $2
limit 5 offset $3
```

```
const posts = await AppDataSource.query(`
  select
  p.*,
  from post p
  left join vote v on p.id = v.post_id and v.user_id = $1
  where p.is_published = true AND p.title ilike OR p.context::text ilike $2
  limit 5 offset $3
 `, [req.user.id, `%${req.query.q}%`, req.query.skip]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a matching pattern missing:

```
p.title ilike OR p.context::text ilike $2
             ^ HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with library you are using but it might be because you are not wrapping it in quotes.

```
const posts = await AppDataSource.query(`
  select
  p.*,
  from post p
  left join vote v on p.id = v.post_id and v.user_id = $1
  where p.is_published = true AND p.title ilike OR p.context::text ilike '$2'
  limit 5 offset $3
 `, [req.user.id, `%${req.query.q}%`, req.query.skip]
)
```

Only changes I have made it **'$2'** which wraps your query in quotes which when translated becomes something like below

```
p.content::text ilike '%somesearchquery%'
```